# Adjusting axis and grid-line appearance in a polar plot

Tags: curated-data, plotting

```
f = PlaneCurveData["Superformula", "PolarEquation"][2, 2, 24, 6, 6, 1, 1][t];

PolarPlot[
 {1.1, 2.0, f},
 {t, 0.0, 2.0 Pi},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PolarAxes -> True,
 PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {
    {1.1, Framed[Style[1.1, 12, Bold], Background -> White]},
    {2.0, Framed[Style[2.0, 12, Bold], Background -> White]}}},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][r]],
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005]]
```

[image]

I have two questions:

**(a)** I find it aesthetically displeasing that the "outer degree circle"  is so far away  from the actual plot,

**(b)** How can  I omit  half of the `PolarGridLines` if I only wanted to plot the maxima, i.e. `0`, `330`, `300`  etc. ?

Comment: You can use: `PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 330 \[Degree], 30 \[Degree]], 
    None}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 2.}`

Comment: And this kind of works for the ticks: `PolarTicks->{{\[Pi],180 \[Degree],{pl,0}},{\[Pi]/2,90 \[Degree],{pl,0}},{2 \[Pi]," 0\[Degree]",{pl,0}},{(3 \[Pi])/2,270 \[Degree],{pl,0}},{{1.1,Framed[Style[1.1,12,Bold],Background->White]},{2.,Framed[Style[2.,12,Bold],Background->White]}}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Kuba, @Rolf Mertig-s comments are summarized by this.

```
f = PlaneCurveData["Superformula", "PolarEquation"][2, 2, 24, 6, 6, 1,1][t];
PolarPlot[{1.1, 2.0, f}, {t, 0.0, 2.0 Pi},
 PolarTicks -> {Table[{i, 180° i/ π}, {i, 0, 11 π/6, π/6}], 
    {{1.1, 
    Framed[Style[1.1, 12, Bold], Background -> White]}, {2., 
    Framed[Style[2., 12, Bold], Background -> White]}}}, 
    ImageSize -> 600, PolarAxes -> True, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t, r}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][r]],
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
    PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 330°, 30°], None}, 
    PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 2.}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you answered both questions. I have added the output :)